# router.refresh(); does not work (I am using Nextjs14)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, crud, next.js13

```
"use client";

import { HiOutlineTrash } from "react-icons/hi";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function RemoveBtn({ id }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const removeTopic = async () => {
    const confirmed = confirm("Are you sure?");

    if (confirmed) {
      const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/topics?id=${id}`, {
        method: "DELETE",
      });

      if (res.ok) {
        router.refresh();
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={removeTopic} className="text-red-400">
      <HiOutlineTrash size={24} />
    </button>
  );
}
```

Was learning a tutorial on CRUD operations with NextJs realized that, the tutorial had Nextjs 13 and I am learning on Nextjs 14. The router.refresh() does not work, I also tried router.reload(), did not work either. Help please

Comment: what you mean with "does not work at all" ?  with  `router.refresh()` you will not lose your current state or browser state ( such current scroll position)